# What are the alternatives when flight is delayed / cancelled due to a strike?

Tags: air-travel

I don't know if anyone is affected by Air France's current strike. If yes and you can't change your travel dates, what did you opt for?

Comment: Welcome! Unlike most other sites, we're not a discussion forum. Instead, we're focused on concrete questions with (preferably) objectively correct answers. This isn't that sort of question: although it has a question mark at the end of it, it's really just an invitation to a discussion. See our [help centre](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the other travel options (assuming those are working fine) :

- short/medium distance : car rental, car sharing, train
- long distance : take another airline (which could eventually lead to non-direct flights)

The problem is that you'll usually need to endorse the costs and then wait for Air France to refund you which could take a very long time based on my experience... Please note that if you are facing troubles to get fully refunded by Air France, you can raise a case with the DGAC (governmental agency). This is free and they will fight with Air France to get your money back.